# Oracle - Selective search in a clob

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I have a clob colum, which stores values like -

```
Row1: <tag name="sdsdf"> Decent <tag name="dfgdfg"> Brag <tag name="dfgdsg"> Nice
Row2: <tag name="dfgsdfg"> Innocent <tag name="dfgds"> Cruel
```

Basically, some values separated by tags. If I query for keyword  "ag", I only want to get Row 1. I would like to ignore anything that's inside < and >.

Answer (score 1):

The *Oracle Text* extension can be used to build information retrieval (full text) index on CLOB data. If you dont use that, you have to do a slow linear substring search. You should avoid that and rethink your architecture (unless of course you talk only about a few MB data total).

Answer (score 0):

that brakes down to 2 conditions in a loop:

1. 'ag' in a string
2. there is no > between position of 'ag' and position of next <
3. repeat for every 'ag'

Can you write it?

or you can write a regexp using regexp_like(string, pattern).